# How to swap the default language mode to mine

Tags: python, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

Here is the code I have given it my own language model's file path

```
import os
from pocketsphinx import LiveSpeech
#if __name__=="__main__":
    speech = LiveSpeech(
    verbose=False,
    sampling_rate=16000,
    buffer_size=2048,
    no_search=False,
    full_utt=False,
    hmm='E:\model\en-us\en-us\\',
    lm='E:\Sphinx 2\pocketsphinx\\bin\Release\Win32\8749.lm',
    dic='E:\Sphinx 2\pocketsphinx\\bin\Release\Win32\8749.dict'
)
```

But this is failing with this error:

```
Allocating 32 buffers of 2500 samples each
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "p.py", line 79, in <module>
    dic='E:\Sphinx 2\pocketsphinx\\bin\Release\Win32\8749.dict'
  File "C:\Users\Shahiryar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pocketsphinx\__init__.py", line 208, in __init__
    super(LiveSpeech, self).__init__(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Shahiryar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pocketsphinx\__init__.py", line 90, in __init__
    super(Pocketsphinx, self).__init__(config)
  File "C:\Users\Shahiryar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pocketsphinx\pocketsphinx.py", line 272, in __init__
    this = _pocketsphinx.new_Decoder(*args)
RuntimeError: new_Decoder returned -1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please, add the error as text instead of an image.

Comment: I have edited the Question

Comment: You can change `verbose=False` to `verbose=True` to see more detailed error message.

Comment: Hi, Mr. Nikolay I have Changed the verbose to True and it says my specified directory for the hmm does not contain acoustic model file named mdef but it is wrong I have checked and Also I have used the pocketsphinx_continuous through windows terminal with the same directory and it worked properly with my assigned language model.

Comment: Anyhow Mr. Nikolay Problem has been solved Thanks a ton man for giving me the response really appreciate it! yout too Mr. Cartucho specially giving my Question an arranged description I learnt a lot. Hats off.